# HTML module with automatic updation in every page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am extremely new to dotnetnuke. I have added an HTML module in home page. I want this module with same content in some other pages and it should be update automatically when i update in home page. How can i implement this in Dotnetnuke?

Please anyone help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the ribbon bar on top of the page, on the common tasks tab, in the Add module section

select the Existing radio button
select your home page in the page drop down
select the module you want a reference to in the Module drop down
click add module

P.S. this question is not programming related and doesn't really belong on SO.  A better place to ask this question is the forums on DotNetNuke.com, you may also want to support the DNN proposal for StackExchange [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15362/dotnetnuke?referrer=3k3sU-glfAVmj6lejTe5CQ2).